# How to pass the variable address of the structure short name to a function

Tags: c, function, variables, struct, memory-address

How can I pass the variable address of the structure short name (`color`) to a function (`fun`) arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun();

struct figure {
    char name[30];
    float field;
} color;

int main(void) {
    fun();  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `color` is the (only) name of a file-scope variable of type `struct figure`.  Are you asking how function `fun` can be made to access that variable directly, or how to pass its address to `fun` as an argument?  Or something else?

Comment: What do you mean "address of the structure short name"? The name has no address, it's just a name for humans.

Comment: That would be `fun(&color); `

Comment: Note: although the terms are sometimes used interchangeably, in  the Standard's language, "parameters" are aspects of function *declarations*, whereas "arguments" are aspects of function *calls*.  You can pass something as an argument, or (less commonly) to a parameter, but not as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to pass the variable address of the structure short name

To pass the address you only need `&color`.

Then the function needs to accept a **pointer to struct figure**.

It may look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


struct figure{
    char name[30];
    float field;
} color;

void fun(struct figure *);  // Function takes pointer to struct figure

int main(void){

    strcpy(color.name, "Joe"); // Initialize color
    color.field = 42.0;

    fun(&color);               // Pass address of color

    return 0;
}

void fun(struct figure *c)
{
    printf("%s\n", c->name);  // Access color using the passed pointer
    printf("%f\n", c->field);
}
```

Output:

```
Joe
42.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

`struct figure { ...  };` would just introduce a new type named `struct figure`, whereas `struct figure { ... } color;` does two things (1) introduce above mentioned type and (2) define a variable named `color` of that type.

To pass an object of type `struct figure` to a function, write...

```
struct figure{
    char name[30];
    float field;
} color;


void fun(struct figure f) {
    printf("%s %f\n", f.name, f.field);
}

int main(void){
    struct figure myObj;
    strcpy(myObj.name, "Hello!");
    myObj.field = 1.0;

    fun(myObj);  

    return 0;
}
```

You could also pass the address of such an object, which would then allow the function to alter the originally passed object as well:

```
void fun(struct figure *f) {
    f->field = 2.0
    printf("%s %f\n", f->name, f->field);
}

int main() {
    ...
    fun(&myObj);
```

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie: The assignment text is rather inprecise (what is "structure short name"?). So I would not count too much on details.